# XML Parsing Error - Yet seems correct

Tags: xml, parsing

I've been modding 7days to Die, a videogame on Steam as of late and it utilizes a number of XML files. I understand the basics and yet, one of the files is encountering an error despite looking, by all means, to be correct.

I am getting this error.

**XML Parsing Error at line 4385
Premature end of data in tag entitygroups line 3**

Pertaining to this line

```
< /entitygroups>
```

Yes, the file begins with < entitygroups> and is sub-divided within with many `< entitygroup>` and `< /entitygroup>` entries.

I do **not** understand why it has an issue with the ending `< /entitygroups>`.

Note I had to put a space in the entitygroups brackets otherwise it wouldnt show here on the forum text.

Here is the Pastebin of the entire file if you are curious.
https://pastebin.com/B2fVPPV9

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly correct - in line #14 tag `entitygroup` missing end-tag `</entitygroup>` in #36

Comment: How on earth do you find such things so quickly. Thank you.

Notepad++ was telling me the error was on line 4385 after all.

Comment: No worries! I work a lot with XML's so I just see something like this :-) Also if some answer helped you just consider marking is as helpful!